# Google Autoaddress: House Name attribute

Tags: jquery-ui

I hope someone can help? I can't find how to return a house name with Google Address AutoComplete. The street_number attribute only returns a house number.

Here are a couple of example addresses:

- Redwood Cottage, Bridge Street, Elgin, UK
- Farm House, Winnersh, Wokingham, UK

I hope someone may be able to find the correct attribute for Redwood Cottage and Farm House in these examples i.e.

```
street_number: 'long_name',
route: 'long_name',
locality: 'long_name',
```

Here are the  attributes I have so far for UK addresses, which I hope is of use to someone:

```
    mapping = {
        'country_id': '{{country.short_name}}',
        'street1': '{{street_number.short_name}} {{route.long_name}}',
        'street2': '{{locality.long_name}}',
        'city': '{{postal_town.long_name}}',
        'postcode': '{{postal_code.short_name}}',
        'region': 'administrative_area_level_2.long_name',
        'region_id': '',
        'region_code': '{{administrative_area_level_1.short_name}}'
    };
```

Comment: When you review all the various attributes, does this data appear in them?

Comment: Also, do you mean this: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete or something else?

Comment: That's the one @Twisty. I've been using the following page for testing: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform . House names are common in the UK and appear on the form, however I can't seem to find the correct attribute to create my own autoaddress code. I've just added the code I have so far above, which I hope someone will find useful :) Any ideas?

Comment: You could simply `console.log(place);` and review the object or iterate each result and review that. This should show you which field or element the item is you're looking for.

Comment: If you want more help, you will have to provide a more complete example.